# How to add custom field CMS block selection in CMS page Magento 2?

Tags: magento2

I want to add a CMS block option on the cms page admin side. Can anyone please guide me?

Like this: https://prnt.sc/KMSLIdK9Vfoe

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to complete your requirement.

> Step1: app/code/Dotsquares/CmsField/registration.php

```
  <?php
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
        \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
        'Dotsquares_CmsField',
        __DIR__
    );
  ?>
```

> Step2: app/code/Dotsquares/CmsField/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Dotsquares_CmsField" />
</config>
```

> Step3: app/code/Dotsquares/CmsField/Setup/InstallSchema.php

```
<?php
    namespace Dotsquares\SellerLocator\Setup;
    
    class InstallSchema implements \Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface
    {
        public function install(\Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface $setup, \Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface $context)
        {
            $installer = $setup;
     
            $installer->startSetup();
    
            $setup->getConnection()->addColumn(
            $setup->getTable('cms_page'),
                'block_id',
                    [
                        'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                        'length' => 255,
                        'nullable' => true,
                        'comment' => 'CMS Block Id'
                    ]
            );
    
            $installer->endSetup();
        }
    }
 ?>
```

> Step4: app/code/Dotsquares/CmsField/view/adminhtml/ui_component/cms_page_form.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="custom_design_update">
        <field name="block_id" formElement="select">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">page</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <label translate="true">CMS Block</label>
            </settings>
            <formElements>
                <select>
                    <settings>
                        <options class="Dotsquares\CmsField\Model\Page\Source\Options"/>
                        <caption translate="true">-- Please Select --</caption>
                    </settings>
                </select>
            </formElements>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

> Step5: app/code/Dotsquares/CmsField/Model/Page/Source/Options.php

```
<?php
namespace Dotsquares\CmsField\Model\Page\Source;

use Magento\Framework\Data\OptionSourceInterface;

class Options implements OptionSourceInterface
{
    protected $_blockFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Cms\Model\BlockFactory $blockFactory
    )
    {
        $this->_blockFactory = $blockFactory;
    }

    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        $blockOptions = $this->_blockFactory->create()->getCollection();
        $options = [];
        foreach ($blockOptions as $key => $value)
        {
            $options[] = [
                'label' => $value->getTitle(),
                'value' => $value->getBlockId(),
            ];
        }
        $this->options = $options;

        return $options;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this answer will help, but i want to add few notes about your code that might help you to improve your skills. 1. missed dependency in `etc/module.xml`. 2. Better use declaration in `etc/db_schema.xml` instead of `InstallSchema`. 3. If you want to use collection better use `CollectionFactory` instead of `ModelFactory`.

Comment: Ok sure, thank you

Comment: @Dotsquares: Thank you for your answer. CMS block is now visible on the cms page, but after saving value is not saved. can you please let me know what is missing from my side?  https://prnt.sc/S2gkaRQ-Luee